# How to get thin QR decomposition in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

When I perform QR decomposition on a 3x2 matrix **A** in Julia, it gives a **3x3 matrix Q**. Is there any way I can get a "thin" version of this QR, where it returns a Q that is 3x2 (same dimensions as matrix A)? My goal is just to get an **orthonormal basis for the column space of A**, so I don't need a 3x3 matrix Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with `Matrix(qr(A))`. `qr` doesn't return matrices, but rather returns an object that can multiply by other matrices or easily extract the thin or full Q matrix.